# Changing HTML that i'm getting from POST before output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a post script in Javascript which is returning HTML that has a div with a class name "guru1", "guru2", etc..

And I want to find a div element inside that div. (which will always be hidden)

and match it with a array i've got to check what guru should I display his block

for ex:

```
$.post('/gurus/home/' ,
        function(data){
           for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                data.find('.guru'+a[i]).find('.element').css('display','block');
           }
          $('#content-bottom').html(data);
});
```

This ofcoruse not working. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(data).find('.guru'+a[i]).find('.element').css('display','block');
```

Comment: For some reason when I changed it to data=$(data). and used the same code I had above it worked.